# gsutil - how to get Android app review report from google play

Tags: android, google-play, gsutil

using [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install#install_archive) how can i view app reviews from google play store ?

so far i have install gsutil and ran gsutil config but its asking me for project ID and i dont have a project ID for apps i made on the play store.  Isn't there a command i can just run to get a report of google play reviews ?

here is what happens when i run gsutil config:

gsutil config

```
This command will create a boto config file at /Users/myuserID/.boto
containing your credentials, based on your responses to the following
questions.
Please navigate your browser to the following URL:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://somesite
In your browser you should see a page that requests you to authorize access to Google Cloud Platform APIs and Services on your behalf. After you approve, an authorization code will be displayed.

Enter the authorization code: 4/....XXXXXX

Please navigate your browser to https://cloud.google.com/console#/project,
then find the project you will use, and copy the Project ID string from the
second column. Older projects do not have Project ID strings. For such projects,
click the project and then copy the Project Number listed under that project.

What is your project-id?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads) and

```
gcloud auth login
gsutil cp gs://pubsite_prod_rev_xxxx/reviews/reviews_com.yyyy.csv .
```